# wp_remote_get times out on api request but jquery GET and postman work?

Tags: theme-development, rest-api, wp-remote-get

I'm working on a project with two themes. Theme 1 contains a custom WP REST endpoint I made. Theme 2 needs to make a GET request to the endpoint. Both projects are hosted locally. When I make a request in postman I get a the data I want. When I go into theme 2 and make a jquery get request like this (next block) I get the data I want...

```
$.get('http://localhost/wp-rest/my-api/v1/my-resource?query=item1,item2,item3', 
function(data) { console.log(data) });
```

However when I try the following, the request times out with an error (I've tried up to 15 seconds for the request).

```
$request = wp_remote_get('http://localhost/wp-rest/my-api/v1/my-resource?query=item1,item2,item3');
if (is_wp_error($request)) {
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($request);
  echo "</pre>";
} else {
  echo "<pre>";
  var_dump($request);
  echo "</pre>";
}
```

from my-controller.php in theme 1

```
class UCT_REST_Magazine_Controller extends WP_REST_Posts_Controller {
  public function __construct() {
    $this->namespace = '/my-api/v1';
    $this->resource_name = 'my-resource';
    $this->post_type = 'post';
    $this->meta = new WP_REST_Post_Meta_Fields($this->post_type);
  }
  public function register_routes() {
    register_rest_route($this->namespace, '/' . $this->resource_name, array(
      array(
        'methods' => 'GET',
        'callback' => array($this, 'get_items')
      )
    ));
  }
  // other functions including get_items()...
}
```

I realize the two `var_dumps` are redundant, but for now I'm just trying to figure out what's going on. Thanks in advance for the help!

Comment: Have you tried using `http://localhost/` instead? Sometimes this can make an issue. Also make sure your API route is configured using the `GET` method.

Comment: sorry that's my fault. I am using `http://` in the code. I just wrote it wrong here. I'll edit my question with that and a snippet of the controller I'm using

Comment: how do you tell between the two var dumps? And does the local loopback work from PHP?

Comment: For the two var dumps my thought was that they should output two different things (either the WP_Error object or a correct JSON response). In all honesty I hadn't thought about that although I suppose I could add strings to tell them apart. As for the loopback, I'm not quite sure what you mean. I figured it would work since my test in postman worked. Totally willing to admit if I'm wrong on that though!

Comment: well. I'm feeling a little foolish now. just came back to this with fresh eyes and realized I didn't encode the query parameters correctly for php.